# Changing Button Colours

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, button, colors, cursor

I am an Advanced Higher Computing student living in Scotland,

I need to create a Game as a project to learn about SDP and software specifications etc. etc...

**I want to click [Button 1] that already has a colour property, then move the cursor to [Button 2] and when I click I want the colour of [Button 2] to change to the colour of [Button 1]**

Is it possible to 'Pick Up' a colour on the VB Form and replicate it onto another button?

Any help or compromise would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumes two buttons on your form, Button1 and Button2:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
  Button2.BackColor = Button1.BackColor
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah yes that is helpful, but if I then had a third button with a different colour and wanted to 'Pick Up' that colour and replicate it to change the colour of Button 2... I actually have a button grid via 2D array of 5x5, and there are 5 different colours on the board. Ideally i would like to click the colour of my choice then move to a 'blank' button and replicate that colour, thanks

Comment: @AdvHStudent376 You should have posted that in your question.  Just create a variable that holds the color value you want and apply it to the button that was clicked.  You can cast the "sender" parameter to the button type to access the BackColor property.